# WooCommer Product Category Loop - How to change the display order of the rating and price?

Tags: customization, hooks, plugins

I want to do a very very simple thing : To re-order the display of the rating and price information on a WooCommerce product category loop. Now in the product category page I got 5 products, all of the same layout:

--THUMBNAIL-- 
| Product name 
| Rating 
| Price 
| Add to Cart

Now I just want to make it like this:

--THUMBNAIL-- 
| Product name 
| Price 
| Rating 
| Add to Cart

I know the code just lies somewhere between the hooks; but just cannot find anyway to make it work. If anyone has ever dealt with this problem, please help show me a way to work with this. I would appreciate this very very very much.

Thank you.

Comment: In your example they are both the same...what changed?

Comment: WooCommerce category loop is handled by WooCommerce standard template or by template in your theme? If so, you should post the code used.

Comment: @splashingpixels Yes that was my typing fault, I edited the post. Your answer worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for stopping by. I have only used standard WooCommerce template so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you just want to swap rating and price where price would come before rating, you would do the following.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 12 );
```

Put these lines of code in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Excellent. Works like a charm. I think I gotta spend more times on this hookie thing. Thank you very much!